# How to add user to group, where group is present in another domain in same forest

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have two domains in two different Identity Source AMCITest.dell.com and AMCETest.usa.com. "AMCETest.usa.com" is a Tree Domain to the forest "AMCITest.dell.com". I have a user "sam" and a group "SID-GRP" in one domain i.e AMCITest.dell.com, the group is universal and another user "rohan" in AMCETest.usa.com. 
I am trying to add ram in SID-GRP. I am unable to add through GUI.

I tried using following command :

```
$AdminCredential = Get-Credential "AMCETest.usa.com\Administrator"
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity SID-GRP -Members AMCETest.usa.com\rohan -Credential $AdminCredential
```

but I am unable to and i am getting the following error :

> Add-ADGroupMember : Authentication failed on the remote side (the
>   stream might still be available for  additional authentication
>   attempts). At line:1 char:1
>   + Add-ADGroupMember -Identity SID-GRP -Members AMCETest.usa.com\rohan -Cred ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (SID-GRP:ADGroup) [Add-ADGroupMember], AuthenticationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationExce
>   ption,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember

If i am wrong in this kindly suggest me the way to add.
Any help is appreciated

Thanks,
Pratik

Comment: Does `AMCETest.usa.com\Administrator` have delegated rights to add users to that group `AMCITest.dell.com`?

Comment: Nope, I din't provided any rights to  'AMCETest.usa.com\Administrator'.

Comment: If it doesn't have rights to add users to that group, then it can't add users to that group. Either use an account in AMCITes` to add users or you need to delegate rights to AMCETest Admin account